# What is the fluid approximation for BCS action?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, fermions

For a system with free fermion gas at finite density (i.e., free Dirac action), we have an ideal fluid description with $\rho$, $p$, $n$. What is the fluid description for BCS action?

Suppose we have a box of Fermi gas, the fermions have BCS type interaction, what is the equation of state? What is $\rho$, $p$, $n$, etc?

Any references on this?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.